# How to forward a response from a remote server in .net core?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I think I've fallen down a rabbit hole, and suspect there is a far easier solution than the one I'm trying. Basically within my .net core MVC app, I want to pull a streaming video file from an external API.

So that means, for any requests to my action, I want to call an external API function across the wire. I need to add a header to the request, but pass on all other headers that have been requested, and then once I've heard back from the API I will forward the response in its entirety to the consumer. It's basically like a Redirect without the StatusCode, and adding a header to the redirected source.

The way I'm doing it is as follows. In my controller, I call a ForwardedResponseResult:

```
var client = await this.FileAssetsApiContext.GetHttpClient();
//Copy the Headers
foreach (var header in Request.Headers)
{
    header.Value.ToList().ForEach(p => {
        if (client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Contains(header.Key))
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove(header.Key);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(header.Key, p);
         }
         else
         {
             client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(header.Key, p);
         }});
    }

    var fullPath = Url.Combine(VideosRootPath, path);
    var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
    return new ForwardedResponseResult(response);
```

And then I have a forwarding class:

```
  public class ForwardedResponseResult : ActionResult
{
    public override void ExecuteResult(ActionContext context)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public ForwardedResponseResult(HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage)
    {
        this.HttpResponseMessage = httpResponseMessage;
    }

    public override async Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
    {
        var responseToCopy = this.HttpResponseMessage;
        var responseToCopyHeaders = responseToCopy.Headers.ToArray();
        var responseToCopyContentHeaders = responseToCopy.Content.Headers.ToArray();
        var streamToCopy = await responseToCopy.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        var responseToReturnTo = context.HttpContext.Response;
        var streamToCopyTo = responseToReturnTo.Body;

        var headers = responseToCopy.Headers.ToArray();
        var contentHeaders = responseToCopy.Content.Headers.ToArray();
        var headersTo = responseToReturnTo.Headers.ToArray();

        foreach (var header in responseToCopy.Headers)
        {
                header.Value.ToList().ForEach(p => responseToReturnTo.Headers.Add(header.Key, p));
        }
        responseToReturnTo.StatusCode = (int) responseToCopy.StatusCode;

        foreach (var header in responseToCopy.Content.Headers)
        {
            header.Value.ToList().ForEach(p => responseToReturnTo.Headers.Add(header.Key, p));
        }

        //Copy to the output buffer
        var remainingBytes = streamToCopy.Length;

        while (remainingBytes > 0)
        {
            //var bufferSize = 1024;
            var bufferSize = 8096;
            var buffLen = remainingBytes > bufferSize ? bufferSize : remainingBytes;
            var buffer = new byte[buffLen];
            streamToCopy.Read(buffer, 0, (int)buffLen);
            streamToCopyTo.Write(buffer, 0, (int)buffLen);
            remainingBytes -= buffLen;
        }
        //streamToCopy.CopyTo(streamToCopyTo);
        //await streamToCopyTo.FlushAsync();

    }
    public HttpResponseMessage HttpResponseMessage { get; }

}
```

This seems like massive overkill, and the performance for range requests is dire. Am I missing something obvious? Is there a way of doing this more simply?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to pull a streaming video file from an external API.

In the case of large downloads, you want to be sure to use [`HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcompletionoption(v=vs.118).aspx). [Otherwise, the `GetAsync` call is actually loading the entire response content into memory (and the `.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync` is not actually asynchronous)](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/efficiently-streaming-large-http-responses-with-httpclient).

Also, you can make use of [the existing `FileStreamResult` type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_File_System_IO_Stream_System_String_). Something like this should work:

```
var client = await this.FileAssetsApiContext.GetHttpClient();
... // Copy Request.Headers to client.DefaultRequestHeaders.

var fullPath = Url.Combine(VideosRootPath, path);
var response = await client.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
var stream = await client.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

... // Copy response.Headers / response.Content.Headers to Response.Headers
return File(stream, "application/octet-stream");
```

I don't know of a clean way to copy request/response headers, but it seems like a good place for a couple of utility methods.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. That change works much better. I'm surprised there is no direct method for doing this, but at least I have it working